# XML Database - High volume capabilites

Tags: scalability, xml-database

What is for you the best XML database capable of managing and querying around 100 000 XML files with some 900Mb files ?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'm biased, but I would recommend you to have a look at BaseX (http://basex.org). What is the approximate total size of the XML documents?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I think the total size can be something like 10 Gb.

Comment: Fine, this should be manageable pretty well. Feel free to give more feedback if you encounter any problems.